# Getting speed tracer source maps to work with Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, profiling

From the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/wiki/ResymbolizationProtocol) Speed tracer should be able to map the GWT java script to the original Java source. I'm unable to get this to work. What I've tried:

Write a symbol manifest and put it in the root of the web app. The symbol manifest contains a link to the super dev mode code server, like this:

```
{ 
  "/plmgwt/91A109F23AF29D16B7122E1BEA5DAB03.cache.js": {
    "symbols": "/WEB-INF/deploy/plmgwt/symbolMaps/91A109F23AF29D16B7122E1BEA5DAB03.symbolMap",
    "sourceServer": "http://localhost:9876/plmgwt/",
    "type": "gwt"
  },

  etc.
}
```

I have the feeling that I shouldn't have to write this manifest myself because the gwt compile could handle this automatically. If so, how do I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I'm taking the wrong approach. With Super Dev Mode one can just use the browsers integrated profiler that uses that SDM generated source maps. So speed tracer is in a way deprecated for Super Dev Mode.